# Reaction of cyclohexene with hydrochloric acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons

What happens when cyclohexene reacts with concentrated hydrochloric acid?
I formed the carbocation intermediate by protonating cyclohexene.
But now I am stuck. I know the end product will be a dimer.
I tried to form a bond between the intermediate and cyclohexene like this.
[image]
Then through rearrangement the plus charge will shift to 3 degree carbon.
In the answer there is a double bond between the two rings. 
That's where I am stuck . I can not think anything further.

Comment: Were you told that a dimer is the product of the reaction? No chlorocyclohexane formed?

Comment: @user55119 In my original question the reaction was with Sulphuric  acid. I don't know how it changed to HCl.

Comment: @VJ: A way to remove traces of alkenes from alkanes (e.g.; cyclohexene from cyclohexane) is to shake the hydrocarbon with conc. sulfuric acid at room temperature, which forms alkyl sulfuric acids. They separate with the sulfuric acid in the oily layer.

Comment: @user55119 So you are saying that instead of dimer, alkyl sulfuric acid will be formed? Maybe both will be formed and the dimer will be the major one?  Though I don't know why.

Comment: @VJ: I believe alkylsulfuric acids are stable at lower temperatures. They can ionize to form carbocations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the mechanism for the dimerization of cyclohexene in strongly acidic medium:

[image]

After the attack of a nucleophile (pi bond) on the electrophilic carbocation, we have:

**A**: joining of the two rings with a bond, and the consequent carbocation (why did it get formed on that position? why not on the adjacent ones?)
**B**: rearrangement of the carbocation (why did it happen?)
**C:** loss of a proton to form the thermodynamically most favorable product (most substituted alkene)

The double bond was formed because of the loss of the $\ce{H+}$ ion in step **C**, formation of a negative charge at that position, and then the delocalisation of that negative charge into the adjacent empty p-orbital (of the $\ce{C+}$ position).

Answer (score 1):

> Then through rearrangement the plus charge will shift to 3 degree carbon.

You're nearly there.
I suggest you draw the 3° carbocation out and think a bit more.
<sup>Hint: Hyperconjugation</sup>

> [image]

Answer (score -1):

Then after the said rearrangement, visualize the lose of proton from the second tertiary carbon atom, giving you your desired product.

Comment: Why will the tertiary carbon lose the proton? Won't the negative charge become unstable due to the  +I effect?

Comment: Maybe because the product is stable

Comment: Okay I got my answer. The charge will be delocalised due to empty p orbital. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep that in mind in the future